# Unable to find element using selenium and phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, maven, selenium, phantomjs

I want to test an application built by AngularJs with selenium and phantomJs driver but i got this error:

```
[ERROR - 2016-06-27T09:42:57.040Z] Session [87123530-3c4b-11e6-bbdd-eb6d6096f6c5] - page.onError - msg: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Main due to:
```

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set
    at http://127.0.0.1:8282/src/MyApp.js:186
   ............

It works with Firefox WebDriver but doesn't works with PhantomJS WebDriver !!!

Answer (score 1):

It could be because PhantomJS, or at least the version of PhantomJS that you're using, doesn't support JavaScript ES6.

In JavaScript ES6, `Set` is defined, but in older versions it is not.